# Bind existing databricks Catalog in unity catalog to the databricks workspace using Terraform

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, terraform-provider-databricks

I have an existing catalog in the unity catalog .We need to bind this catalog to particular databricks worksapce.Is it possible to assign existing catalog to the new workspace?  I found we can can assign the catalog to the workspace during catalog creation.But we have requirement to assign existing catalog the Azure Databricks worksapce using terrafom.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [catalog_workspace_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/catalog_workspace_binding) resource for that:

```
resource "databricks_catalog_workspace_binding" "sandbox" {
  catalog_name = databricks_catalog.sandbox.name
  workspace_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.ws.workspace_id
}
```

and make sure that the isolation mode is set to `ISOLATED` as mentioned in the docs.